# Chart-JS: table under x axes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chart.js

i would like to display a web graph and i have some experience with ChartJS.
My scope is to display a table (grid) under the x axes.
[Here is an excel sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDIna.png)

Is there any way?
Also writing custom html code.

Thanks

Comment: Is there as reason you can't just add a `<table>` underneath and size the columns yourself?

Comment: Here's an article that lets you create a table from *chart-data*.  Looks like it's intended to be reusable (ie to work for any chart).  If you know your chart data up-front, then it's easier to just create the table yourself   http://codingstill.com/2016/01/create-html-table-from-chartjs-data/